# HTML Grid system - div order in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap Grid System like this:
[Grid System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50uxp.png)

When I display this in mobile, the ".col-12 .col-md-8" is always in first row.

.col-12 .col-md-8

.col-6 .col-md-4

How to make ".col-6 .col-md-4" to be the first?

**.col-6 .col-md-4**

**.col-12 .col-md-8**

Thank you!

Comment: This is explained in the [Reordering section of the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering).

Answer (score 1):

The CSS "Order" property, combined with a media query, can be used to re-order columns when they get stacked in smaller screens.

Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #first {
        order: 2;
    }
    #second {
        order: 4;
    }
    #third {
        order: 1;
    }
    #fourth {
        order: 3;
    }
}
```

You could replace the ID's in my code with your column classes such as `.col-6` but that will apply to the entire site. You might not want to do that. That is why I left ID's such as `#first`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap order class:

.col-12 .col-md-8 .order-2

.col-6 .col-md-4 .order-1

or

.col-12 .col-md-8 .order-last

.col-6 .col-md-4 .order-first

Here get the official link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering